# Subtract days from date, and then round result to end of week date in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Sorry if this sounds a little confusing...

I'm working with a table that aggregates data at a weekly level, from Sunday to Saturday. The date column stores the end of week date; last week, for example, would have been an end of week date of 2019-01-19.

I'm trying to get total records from last week's end date, 2019-01-19, subtract 360 days. However, if I subtract 360 days, and the date does not fall on Saturday, records will be ignored.

How can I subtract 360 days from 2019-01-19, and make sure the day the calculation falls on also rounds to the end of that week's date?

2019-01-19 - 360 = 2018-01-24, which is a Wednesday. I want it to round to the Saturday of that week, 2018-01-27

Comment: So you basically would like to subtract a multiple of instead of 360?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work
I have not tested, but you see the idea and can modify accordingly to your needs

```
select (date_trunc('week','2019-01-19'::date) - (interval '1 week' * floor(360/7))) + interval '6 days';
```

If its close and you cannot see what to change to make it work - then leave a comment.

Comment: Don't get it fully (the interval +6 days part for example), but will play around with it

Comment: the idea is to 1) go to the first day of the week 2) subtract the right number of weeks 3) add 6 days to get to the last day of the week

Answer (score 0):

In Google BigQuery standard SQL you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(<YOUR_DATE>), INTERVAL -360 DAY), WEEK(SATURDAY))
```